# Get keyboard input without requiring root and without x11

Tags: xorg, keyboard, c++, input-devices

I'm trying to capture keyboard input in a C/C++ program without requiring root privileges and without the use of X11 `XNextEvent()`.

I've tried to open the device directly, but for obvious security reasons, accessing hardware directly requires root permissions. The device I'm trying to open is `/dev/input/by-id/(my keyboard name here)` which maps to an event pipe(`/dev/input/event<#>`) that requires root in order to read.

X11 library allows me to capture keyboard events(using `XNextEvent`), but I can't rely on the client having X11 installed for cases in which they want to run headless and without the GUI.

I need to be able to capture all keyboard keys, including the <kbd>shift</kbd>, <kbd>alt</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>, and <kbd>super</kbd>(windows or mac) key. Preferably, I'd also like to capture media keys such as play, volume up/down, etc and only when the application has focus.

Does anyone know how I might be able to do this?

I've thought of just doing two different code paths for input, one for headless in which they would pull events just using stdin(but this won't catch the shift key AFAIK), and the other path uses X11, but I'd like to only have to maintain one keyboard input system if possible.

Comment: Ken, did you manage to find a solution, 5 years later?

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I could find is to make a separate daemon that run as service which monitor `/dev/input/..` events and let the other user tools to connect to itself and listen for input events.

Think something that replace XEvent. (bringing those input events to user space)

Comment: Thanks! I would like to avoid having to require root privileges for the application(that would also include the install process) but it looks like I have no other choice. There really should be a user level input management system for Linux!